# How to get string value from Controller method to a View script tag variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a method inside of a controller, for example

```
private string GetString()
{
    return "Hi string";
}
```

And variable in the View inside of `<script>` tags:

```
<script> let str = ""; </script>
```

How do i get the string from the method in controller?

```
<script> let str = Controller.GetString(); </script>
```

Travis helped me with this:

```
@using ThrowAwayWeb.Helper;

<h2>Index</h2>
<h2>@ViewHelpers.GetString()</h2>
<script>let str = @ViewHelpers.GetString();</script>
```

But JavaScript is encoding characters, in that case a little change is needed

```
<script>let str = @Html.Raw(@ViewHelpers.GetString());</script>
```

Also i found interesting option, put a Razor call inside double quotes:

```
<script>let str = "@Html.Raw(@ViewHelpers.GetString());"</script>
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't call controller methods directly from the view. Instead, here are some alternatives: 1. create the method in the model instead, 2. pass the method result from the controller to the view via the ViewState, or 3. retrieve the result by making an AJAX call to a controller action

Comment: @Kei could you please provide some link? It is hard to follow just your actions without screenshots or examples.

Comment: Give me a sec, I'll write an example.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kei's great answer (which covers the most appropriate usage for most situations), another option:

Create a static class:

```
    namespace ThrowAwayWeb.Helper
    {
        public static class ViewHelpers
        {
            public static string GetString() { return "Hi String"; }
        }
    }
```

Load and use it directly in your view:

```
    @using ThrowAwayWeb.Helper;


    <h2>Index</h2>
    <h2>@ViewHelpers.GetString()</h2>
    <script>let str = @ViewHelpers.GetString();</script>
```

Comment: Added @using as you have, but it shows the error that i don't have ViewHelpers.

Comment: That is the name of the static class created in the first code section. If you haven't created it yet, then it will show error. In the above example, my projects namespace is "ThrowAwayWeb" . In my project I have a folder called "Helper" . In that folder I have a static class named "ViewHelpers". In that static class I have a static method named "GetString()"

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe controller methods can be called directly from the view. Instead, here are three alternative approaches.

**Approach 1: Move method to model**

Model class

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string GetString() 
    {
        return "Hi string";
    }
}
```

View

```
@model SomeModel   
// The above should be on the first line.

// Script portion of the view
<script> let str = "@Model.GetString()"; </script>
```

**Approach 2: Pass data from controller to view via ViewData(or ViewBag)**

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // The key, "GetStringResult" is arbitrary. 
    // Whatever value you assign to this key can be accessed from the view using the same key.
    ViewData["GetStringResult"] = GetString();
    return View();
}

private string GetString() 
{
    return "Hi string";
}
```

View

```
<script> let str = '@ViewData["GetStringResult"]'; </script>
```

**Approach 3: Convert method on Controller to public Action, and retrieve result via AJAX**

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetString()
{
    return "Hi string";
}
```

View

```
<script> 
    let str = "";
    // Using jQuery
    // Note that str will only get set after the request is done.
    $.get(@Url.Action("GetString", "ControllerName")).done(function(data) {
        str = data;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: None of this seems to be working. The first does not recognize @model (i have controllers). The second does not have ViewState, only ViewData. Even though it does not work if Change ViewState on ViewData. The third, i use pure JS not jquery, tried it anyway, but same, does not work.

Comment: @Nar Jovan you are using ASP.NET MVC and your view is a Razor (.cshtml) file right? Also, my apologies, yes you are correct it should be ViewData not ViewState.